# turtlebot installation with Gazebo 5 on Indigo

Tags: gazebo, turtlebot, ros-jade, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04.

I have Jade with default Gazebo (5) installed for a course I'm taking.
Then my other course requires Indigo. So I installed Indigo as second ROS on my system and this is where my problem begins.This is my steps:

1. I installed ros-indigo-desktop.
2. Since I already have Gazebo 5, I only installed ros-indigo-gazebo5-ros-pkgs following this link
   http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_wrapper_versions

Everything seems fine. Then I moved on to installing turtlebot. http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot/Tutorials/indigo/Debs%20Installation

1. Then I can't install ros-indigo-turtlebot-simulator,
2. because ros-indigo-turtlebot-simulator can't be installed
3. because ros-indigo-turtlebot-simulator can't be installed, which looks for gazebo2

Is there a way to resolve this dependency issue?
I don't have to use gazebo 5 on Indigo, but I can't install ros-indigo-desktop-full due to Gazebo 5 on Jade.

Thanks

---

UPDATE
I ended up installing packages from source. http://answers.ros.org/question/208963/installing-package-from-source-in-indigo/ Things are installed, but I haven't tried interacting with the hardware yet using these packages yet.

First turtlebot_simulator, and kobuki_desktop from source http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_simulator?distro=indigo , http://wiki.ros.org/kobuki_desktop

Then the rest from source: http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot/Tutorials/indigo/Source%20Installation (without the first step these install from source would still complain about missing/unable to install packages depending on gazebo2)

(Note: For some reason I would get multiple package with same name errors during rosdep install at the second step. I had to manually remove the duplicates.)

---

UPDATE 2
I'm having problem with moving Indigo turtlebot in Gazebo5. its almost as if it doesn't move. If I hold the move key on turtlebot_telop long enough, I could see the displacement. I might stop pursuing this matter and consider  suggestions below

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253659/turtlebot-installation-with-gazebo-5-on-indigo/) by [CodingPeon](https://answers.ros.org/users/29242/codingpeon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2017-02-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As you've probably noticed, the supported Gazebo versions on Indigo and on Jade are different; [Indigo 2.x](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Migration#Gazebo) and [Jade 5.x](http://wiki.ros.org/jade/Migration#Gazebo_Simulator). As noted in the link there's a way to use Gazebo5 on Indigo, but if you don't need to use 5 on Indigo the simplest way might be to un/install every time you switch ROS distribution.

---

UPDATE1.

@Peon said:

> Are you suggesting deb install gazebo2 and turtlebot + all dependency on indigo first. Then when i work on the other project on Jade, uninstall only gazebo2 package. Install Gazebo 5 on Jade. Then when i go back to Indigo again remove only Gazebo5 and install Gazebo 2?

Yes. It's unfortunate that I can't think of any better option, but thanks to deb binaries un/installing packages is simple enough and far freer from errors than building source.

---

UPDATE2

There's a [discussion](https://discourse.ros.org/t/development-setup-for-multiple-ros-distros/1280/6) about having multiple ros distros installed on a single OS.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2017-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [CodingPeon](https://answers.ros.org/users/29242/codingpeon/) on 2017-02-05**:
I'm aware of the default support Gazebo version. Unfortunately I'm working on both projects at the same time, and most like require to use Gazebo on both.

**Comment by [CodingPeon](https://answers.ros.org/users/29242/codingpeon/) on 2017-02-05**:
Are you suggesting deb install gazebo2 and turtlebot + all dependency on indigo first. Then when i work on the other project on Jade, uninstall **only** gazebo2 package. Install Gazebo 5 on Jade.
Then when i go back to Indigo again remove **only** Gazebo5 and install Gazebo 2?